# How to format "2017-02-03T13:41:17 UTC" using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have tried to do the following

`moment.tz("2017-02-03T13:41:17 UTC", moment.tz.guess()).format(DEFAULT.formats.timestamp)`

but it is returning "Invalid Date"

Comment: How about `Date.parse`? Because `new Date(Date.parse("2017-02-03T13:41:17Z"));` is pretty swell...

Comment: _Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info._

Comment: Also read this: https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/294

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first parse with moment, and then pass the moment object to `moment.tz`:

`moment.tz(moment('2017-02-03T13:41:17 UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss ZZ'), moment.tz.guess())`

Answer (score 0):

`moment.tz('2017-02-03T13:41:17', 'UTC')`

Answer (score 0):

If you're converting a UTC datetime to a different timezone use the following:

`moment.utc("2017-02-03T13:41:17 UTC".replace(" UTC", "")).tz(moment.tz.guess()).format(DEFAULT.formats.timestamp)`.